# run independent .php inside laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I recently installed laravel framework in my laptop.I installed laravel in my Xampp server's htdocs/laravel/laravel source path

How can I <strike>run</strike> execute written PHP codes normally in browsers and <strike>run</strike> execute them out side laravel framework?

That means if I create a new .php file in desktop that will show "hello world". Where I should keep that file or in which folder to show my this individual file run in browser only inside laravel framework.

Comment: I just want to run a hello.php file containing echo "hello" in browser as I do in localhost before setting up laravel

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: He means point his browser to the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it inside your `public` directory. If your application has a domain of localhost you can access it via localhost/script.php. BUT this is extremely ill-advised as you are opening yourself to potential vulnerabilities depending on what your script does.

If it is for testing then fine. Otherwise you will have to put that somewhere in your application say `app/scripts/script.php` where it cannot be accessed via the browser (the only point of stand-alone scripts in web application is for CRON tasks or for CLI commands). If this is the case, you may want to take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands about writing your own artisan commands.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing that code in a custom library inside of Laravel and including it within a controller.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new file named `filename.blade.php` in the `resources/views` directory.
- In the view file, add the HTML, PHP, and/or Blade templates that define the structure and layout of the page.
- Save the view file.
- In the `routes/web.php` file, add the following route:

```
Route::get("/filename", function() {
    // Return the view file.
    return view('filename');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your PHP file inside your **storage/app/public/filename.php** folder in your laravel application folder and can run like 
**your_domain_name/storage/filename.php**

Comment: but its easy way to do it.